# The derived pushforward between derived categories of twisted sheaves preserves (possibly infinite) direct sums

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes over some base. It is [known](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08FB) that, under suitable hypotheses ($f$ quasi-compact and quasi-separated), the induced derived pushforward
\begin{equation}
\mathbb R f_* \colon \mathsf{D}(\operatorname{QCoh}(X)) \to \mathsf{D}(\operatorname{QCoh}(Y))
\end{equation}
preserves (possibly infinite) direct sums.

I would like to prove (if possible) the analogous statement for *derived categories of twisted sheaves* ([here](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~andreic/publications/ThesisSingleSpaced.pdf) an introduction to these objects). Namely, let $\beta$ be an element of the Brauer group of $Y$, and let $\alpha = f^* \beta$ the corresponding element of the Brauer group of $X$. A derived pushforward functor can be defined between the derived categories of twisted quasi-coherent sheaves:
\begin{equation}
\mathbb R f_* \colon \mathsf{D}(\operatorname{QCoh}(X,\alpha)) \to \mathsf{D}(\operatorname{QCoh}(Y,\beta)).
\end{equation}
Does it preserve direct sums? I was wondering if one can prove this statement just using the result in the untwisted case, or if one needs a different approach.

Comment: All the functors used obviously preserve direct sums, so isn't this obvious?

Comment: I think he means possibly infinite direct sums. This should be true by noticing that QCoh(X,a) is a subcategory of QCoh of the total stack of a. Then you can use the result you cite but for Artin stacks.

Comment: Yes, I meant all direct sums. I edited. I was also wondering if there were a direct, "hands on" argument.